# Global search using filters and services

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

My purpose is to create a global search toolbar, where I can search any data in the app.

I'm already using filters to search a single type of resource, like :

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:projectFilter">
 /* TODO template */
</div>
```

The projects array is bound to the **$scope** and the data is fetched by a **ProjectsService**.

I want to search for any data in the application like projects, customers, etc..
I was thinking about an input and a select tag. The select choose the resource i need to filter and the input the resource name.

Is there a way to dinamically change the **projects** array into something else at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the names of the available arrays and you have them all in $scope, there should be no problem:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    ...
    <select ng-model="haystack" ng-options="model for model in models">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    ...
    <input type="search" ng-model="needle" placeholder="search query..." />
    ...
    Results: {{(results = search(haystack, needle) || []).length}}
    <ul><li ng-repeat="item in results">...</li></ul>
    ...

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($filter, $scope) {
    $scope.models = ['customers', 'projects'];
    $scope.projects = [...];
    $scope.customers = [...];

    $scope.search = function (haystack, needle) {
        var arr = (haystack && $scope[haystack]) ? $scope[haystack] : [];
        if (!needle) return arr;

        return $filter('filter')(arr, needle);
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/S7Djk/)**.